# ImportError: Can't determine version for openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

`

```
from pandas import *
from openpyxl import *


print("Wpisz slowo ktore chcesz usunac:")  
Szukaj = str(input(""))
xlsx = ExcelFile('C:/Users/krzys/Desktop/Python/test.xlsx')
File = xlsx.parse(xlsx.sheet_names[0])
print(File.to_dict())
```

`

I am working on accessing an excel file. I have found a piece of code above and I decided to use it. I installed pandas and openpyxl in order to use the functions. I used pip install commands.

When I run the code I am receiving the following logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\krzys\Desktop\Python\Drafts and Tests\xml.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openpyxl import *
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 25, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 27, in <module>
    from openpyxl.styles import numbers, is_date_format
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .alignment import Alignment
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl.descriptors import Bool, MinMax, Min, Alias, NoneSet
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .sequence import Sequence
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openpyxl.xml.functions import Element
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\xml\functions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import (
  File "c:\Users\krzys\Desktop\Python\Drafts and Tests\xml.py", line 7, in <module>
    xlsx = ExcelFile('C:/Users/krzys/Desktop/Python/test.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 556, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 157, in import_optional_dependency
    version = get_version(module_to_get)
  File "C:\Users\krzys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 83, in get_version
    raise ImportError(f"Can't determine version for {module.__name__}")
ImportError: Can't determine version for openpyxl
```

I ran pip install pandas
`PS C:\Users\krzys\Desktop\Python> pip install pandas Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.5.1) Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.23.4) Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.5) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)`

and openpyxl
`Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.0.10) Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0) PS C:\Users\krzys\Desktop\Python>`

Pip show openpyxl
`pip show openpyxl Name: openpyxl Version: 3.0.10 Summary: A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files Home-page: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io Author: See AUTHORS Author-email: charlie.clark@clark-consulting.eu License: MIT Location: c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages Requires: et-xmlfile Required-by: PS C:\Users\krzys\Desktop\Python>`

pip show pandas
`Name: pandas Version: 1.5.1 Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org Author: The Pandas Development Team Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org License: BSD-3-Clause Location: c:\users\krzys\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz Required-by:`
Can you please help me out with this error?

I googled possible solutions online, tried conda install but to no avail. I tried changing the PATH (tried fix from issues with pip) to it but it only deactivated PIP so I fixed my PIP and came back to this error again.

I also tried to reinstall and install openpyxl but it did not fix the issue.